# Stop Mapbox.js from re-mounting on every state change?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, mapbox

I am running into a particularly painful issue utilising react/redux/mapbox and was hoping to get some advice. I have a container component which houses both a Map component and a destination bar component which shows information about the route. I also need to expose the mapbox instance to the window object when it is available.

The problem I seem to be having is that when I render the Map component, i need to wait for the mapbox.load event, at which point I can then set the map instance to either a useState or useRef for later use in the code. If I set it as state then the map enters into a endless loop where it sets the state, re-loads the map and tries to set the state again. If I set it as a ref, then it wont re-render any of the details on the other component. Also if I were to use the window.map instance at any point it also re-mounts the Map component and starts this whole process off again.

```
function App() {
const { data, isError } = useConfigEndpointQuery();
  const { route, to, from, routingDestinationData, routingOverviewData } =
    useAppSelector((state) => state.routing);

  const modals = useAppSelector((state) => state.ui.modals);
  const mapInstance = useRef<LivingMap>();

  const [isUserActive, setIsUserActive] = useState(false);
  const [mode, setMode] = useState(ComponentMode.OVERVIEW);
  const [isStaticUserLocationChevron, setIsStaticUserLocationChevron] =
    useState(false);
  const [countdownTimeInSeconds, setCountdownTimeInSeconds] = useState(
    INITIAL_COUNTDOWN_TIME / 1000
  );

  const countdownInterval = useRef<NodeJS.Timer | undefined>();
  const userActiveInterval = useRef<NodeJS.Timer | undefined>();
  const setChevronInterval = useRef<NodeJS.Timer | undefined>();

  const userLocationControl = useRef<UserLocationControl>();
  const routingControl = useRef<RoutingControl>();
  const geofenceControl = useRef<GeofenceControl>();
  const floorControl = useRef<FloorControl>();

  return data ? (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <TopBar distance={totalLength} time={totalTime} />
      <Map
        bearing={data.areas[0].view.bearing}
        zoom={data.areas[0].view.zoom}
        maxZoom={data.areas[0].view.maxZoom}
        minZoom={data.areas[0].view.minZoom}
        center={data.areas[0].view.center}
        extent={data.areas[0].view.extent}
        floor={data.floors.find((floor) => !!floor.default)!.universal_id}
        floors={data.floors}
        mapStyle={`${getUrl(URLTypes.STYLES)}/styles.json`}
        accessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN as string}
        onMapReady={(map) => {
          mapInstance.current = map;
          userLocationControl.current = map.getPluginById<UserLocationControl>(
            PLUGIN_IDS.USER_LOCATION
          );
          routingControl.current = map.getPluginById<RoutingControl>(
            PLUGIN_IDS.ROUTING
          );
          geofenceControl.current = map.getPluginById<GeofenceControl>(
            PLUGIN_IDS.GEOFENCE
          );
          floorControl.current = map.getPluginById<FloorControl>(
            PLUGIN_IDS.FLOOR
          );
        }}
      />
    </div>
  ) : isError ? (
    <div>Error loading config</div>
  ) : null;
}
```

Is there a way by which I can keep a single instance of a mapbox map while also reading/writing data to the redux store and interacting with the map instance without causing the component to re-mount the map component each time?

Answer (score 0):

It appears it was re-rendering needlessly as I was passing a function into the map component without wrapping it in useCallback()